# angularjs directive losing array format filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

I am trying to do a simple array sort in a directive.
But somehow when i put the nested array in the orderBy filter it is losing array and becomes an object (which can not be ordered)

when i log out the scope.item inside the directive it says:
addresses: Array[2]

but when trying to filter using
$filter('orderBy')(scope.item.addresses, 'distance');
i am getting "TypeError: object is not a function"

```
(function(angular){
'use strict';
angular.module('starter').directive('getDistance', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, $filter) {

            ;
            console.log(scope.item);

            scope.item.addresses = $filter('orderBy')(, scope.item.addresses, 'distance');

            console.log(scope.item.addresses);
        }
    };
});
})(window.angular);
```

Comment: You have an extra comma right after '$filter('orderBy')('. Typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `inject` filter in the directive definision not in the linking function.

```
angular.module('starter').directive('getDistance', function($filter) {
```

Or

```
angular.module('starter').directive('getDistance', ['$filter', function($filter) {..
```

and do (Removing the extra comma, which probably is a typo):

```
scope.item.addresses = $filter('orderBy')(scope.item.addresses, 'distance');
```